# md5 password hash

Tags: centos, security, password

I'm looking to create a md5 hash to use in /etc/shadow.
Someone suggested using grub-crypt.
Every time I put the same password in I get a different hash.

```
[root@endpoint ~]# grub-crypt --md5
Password: 
Retype password: 
$1$dd3MRM3g$WZkIt4KDQgrKZ4D1d71dz1
[root@endpoint ~]# grub-crypt --md5
Password: 
Retype password: 
$1$Z5XNluIC$bt1In4cu5qdCKPMCf1lV71
[root@endpoint ~]#
```

I believe this is because of the salt.

from man crypt

```
So $5$salt$encrypted is an SHA-256 encoded password and $6$salt$encrypted is an SHA-512 encoded one.
```

but what if I don't want to use a salt is that possible to store something in /etc/shadow without it ?

Assuming I wanted to use

```
[root@endpoint ~]# echo -n mypassword | md5sum 
34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44  -
[root@endpoint ~]#
```

**Question**

What should /etc/shadow look like if I don't use the salt ? Or by design will it never work ? I'm aware its less secure.

```
[root@endpoint ~]# grep someaccount /etc/shadow
someaccount:$1$34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44:16494$:0:99999:7:::
[root@endpoint ~]#
```

Thanks

Comment: "I'm looking to create a md5 hash to use in /etc/shadow." A reasonable question is, why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know. I'm not trying to do anything I just want to know how to make it work without the salt or indeed whether its possible.

Comment: The system does something like that when creating an account, and even when changing a password. You could take a look at how this is done when creating an account. So you could look at `adduser` or `useradd` or `passwd` and work downwards.

Comment: **Question**

What should /etc/shadow look like if I don't use the salt ? Or by design will it never work ? I'm aware its less secure.